# How to split a text by a whole line using regex

Tags: c#, regex

I have a text, something like this:

```
Data data
data data blah blah
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
Data data
data data blah blah
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
Data data
data data blah blah
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
Data data
data data blah blah
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I want to split it on `---------`I have tried this:

```
string[] splitted = Regex.Split(text, "[-][\r][\n]?");
```

it does split it, but in a wrong way, it take the last `-` only.

What's the correct regext to split this removing the whole dashes. BTW, the data has single dashes here and there, I only want to split it when there is many dashes followed by new line.

Comment: Use `string.Split` on the string `-------------------------------------------------------------------------` ?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum some times dashes are not fixed in length..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to use appropriate quantifier. You should split on 1 or more `-`. Currently you are splitting on just 1. Also, point to note, `[\r][\n]?` will not match single `\n`, you should consider that also:

Try using this regex:

```
Regex.Split(text, "-+(?:\r\n|\r|\n)?");
```

You can make the group captured to allow matching the last `---`, which doesn't end with newline.

Comment: I like all the regex ninjas who does answer on SO

Comment: Will this help if there is no new line character at the end? Because when there is last ------------ it will not remove the ------

Comment: @NisargShah. Edited regex. Just make the group optional. Notice that I changed the way you matched newlines.

Comment: @Heather don't just like him, let him take you on a date. maybe he can show you some regex tricks :p

Answer (score 0):

```
var parts = Regex.Split(text, "(?<=\r\n|^)-------------------------------------------------------------------------(?:\r\n|$)")
```

Meaning: many ----- preceded by a new line or the beginning of the string and followed by a new line or the end of the string.

The advantage is that it won't cut on random `-` present in the text.

Shorter:

```
var parts = Regex.Split(text, "(?<=\r\n|^)-{73}(?:\r\n|$)")
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [RegexOptions.Multiline](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions.aspx) option:

```
            string text = @"data1
data1-1
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
data2
data2-1
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
data3
data3-1";
            Regex re = new Regex(@"^-+", RegexOptions.Multiline);
            string[] matches = re.Split(text);
            foreach (string match in matches)
                Console.WriteLine("match = " + match/*.Trim()*/);
```

prints

```
match = data1
data1-1

match =
data2
data2-1

match =
data3
data3-1
```